# Default + Zones Show Up in Check out??? - Woocommerce Custom Shipping Method Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've built my first shipping method plugin based on flat rate with a few extra fields.

I have done the following:
1. Installed and activated the plugin
2. Added 2 instances of the shipping method to the UK zone

I can see in the top sub menu in the shipping section there appears to be some kind of "default" instance of the shipping plugin in a menu labelled "UK Flat Rate"

I was wondering if there's a way to remove this and ONLY have the plugin work in the shipping zones section.

The reason I ask is that then in checkout if I enter a UK address I see the 2 UK methods defined and then underneath them both there is also a radio button for UK Flat Rate which I'm trying to get rid of. It shows the default values based on the values entered in the sub-section.

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
exit;
}

if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'uk_shipping_method');
function uk_shipping_method() {
    if (!class_exists('UK_WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate')) {
    class UK_WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate extends WC_Shipping_Method {

        /** @var string cost passed to [fee] shortcode */
        protected $fee_cost = '';

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param int $instance_id
         */

        public function __construct($instance_id = 1) {
            $this->id                    = 'uk_flat_rate';
            $this->instance_id           = absint($instance_id);
            $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
            $this->method_title          = __('UK Flat Rate');
            $this->title          = 'UK Flat Rate';
            $this->method_description    = __('Lets you charge a fixed rate for shipping but flags for UK Status Update.');
            $this->supports              = array(
                'shipping-zones',
                'instance-settings',
                'instance-settings-modal',
            );
            $this->init();

            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options'));
        }

        /**
         * init user set variables.
         */
        public function init() {
            $this->instance_form_fields = include('includes/settings-flat-rate.php');
            $this->title                = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->tax_status           = $this->get_option( 'tax_status' );
            $this->cost                 = $this->get_option( 'cost' );
            $this->type                 = $this->get_option( 'type', 'class' );
        }

        /**
         * Evaluate a cost from a sum/string.
         * @param  string $sum
         * @param  array  $args
         * @return string
         */
        protected function evaluate_cost( $sum, $args = array() ) {
            include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/libraries/class-wc-eval-math.php' );

            // Allow 3rd parties to process shipping cost arguments
            $args           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_evaluate_shipping_cost_args', $args, $sum, $this );
            $locale         = localeconv();
            $decimals       = array( wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['mon_decimal_point'], ',' );
            $this->fee_cost = $args['cost'];

            // Expand shortcodes
            add_shortcode( 'fee', array( $this, 'fee' ) );

            $sum = do_shortcode( str_replace(
                array(
                    '[qty]',
                    '[cost]',
                ),
                array(
                    $args['qty'],
                    $args['cost'],
                ),
                $sum
            ) );

            remove_shortcode( 'fee', array( $this, 'fee' ) );

            // Remove whitespace from string
            $sum = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $sum );

            // Remove locale from string
            $sum = str_replace( $decimals, '.', $sum );

            // Trim invalid start/end characters
            $sum = rtrim( ltrim( $sum, "\t\n\r\0\x0B+*/" ), "\t\n\r\0\x0B+-*/" );

            // Do the math
            return $sum ? WC_Eval_Math::evaluate( $sum ) : 0;
        }

        /**
         * Work out fee (shortcode).
         * @param  array $atts
         * @return string
         */
        public function fee( $atts ) {
            $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                'percent' => '',
                'min_fee' => '',
                'max_fee' => '',
            ), $atts, 'fee' );

            $calculated_fee = 0;

            if ( $atts['percent'] ) {
                $calculated_fee = $this->fee_cost * ( floatval( $atts['percent'] ) / 100 );
            }

            if ( $atts['min_fee'] && $calculated_fee < $atts['min_fee'] ) {
                $calculated_fee = $atts['min_fee'];
            }

            if ( $atts['max_fee'] && $calculated_fee > $atts['max_fee'] ) {
                $calculated_fee = $atts['max_fee'];
            }

            return $calculated_fee;
        }

        /**
         * calculate_shipping function.
         *
         * @param array $package (default: array())
         */
        public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
            $rate = array(
                'id'      => $this->get_rate_id(),
                'label'   => $this->title,
                'cost'    => 0,
                'package' => $package,
            );

            // Calculate the costs
            $has_costs = false; // True when a cost is set. False if all costs are blank strings.
            $cost      = $this->get_option('cost');

            if ( '' !== $cost ) {
                $has_costs    = true;
                $rate['cost'] = $this->evaluate_cost( $cost, array(
                    'qty'  => $this->get_package_item_qty( $package ),
                    'cost' => $package['contents_cost'],
                ) );
            }

            // Add shipping class costs.
            $shipping_classes = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes();

            if ( ! empty( $shipping_classes ) ) {
                $found_shipping_classes = $this->find_shipping_classes( $package );
                $highest_class_cost     = 0;

                foreach ( $found_shipping_classes as $shipping_class => $products ) {
                    // Also handles BW compatibility when slugs were used instead of ids
                    $shipping_class_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' );
                    $class_cost_string   = $shipping_class_term && $shipping_class_term->term_id ? $this->get_option( 'class_cost_' . $shipping_class_term->term_id, $this->get_option( 'class_cost_' . $shipping_class, '' ) ) : $this->get_option( 'no_class_cost', '' );

                    if ( '' === $class_cost_string ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $has_costs  = true;
                    $class_cost = $this->evaluate_cost( $class_cost_string, array(
                        'qty'  => array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $products, 'quantity' ) ),
                        'cost' => array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $products, 'line_total' ) ),
                    ) );

                    if ( 'class' === $this->type ) {
                        $rate['cost'] += $class_cost;
                    } else {
                        $highest_class_cost = $class_cost > $highest_class_cost ? $class_cost : $highest_class_cost;
                    }
                }

                if ( 'order' === $this->type && $highest_class_cost ) {
                    $rate['cost'] += $highest_class_cost;
                }
            }

            // Add the rate
            if ( $has_costs ) {
                $this->add_rate( $rate );
            }

            /**
             * Developers can add additional flat rates based on this one via this action since @version 2.4.
             *
             * Previously there were (overly complex) options to add additional rates however this was not user.
             * friendly and goes against what Flat Rate Shipping was originally intended for.
             *
             * This example shows how you can add an extra rate based on this flat rate via custom function:
             *
             *      add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate', 'add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );
             *
             *      function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
             *          $new_rate          = $rate;
             *          $new_rate['id']    .= ':' . 'custom_rate_name'; // Append a custom ID.
             *          $new_rate['label'] = 'Rushed Shipping'; // Rename to 'Rushed Shipping'.
             *          $new_rate['cost']  += 2; // Add $2 to the cost.
             *
             *          // Add it to WC.
             *          $method->add_rate( $new_rate );
             *      }.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $this->id . '_shipping_add_rate', $this, $rate );
        }

        /**
         * Get items in package.
         * @param  array $package
         * @return int
         */
        public function get_package_item_qty( $package ) {
            $total_quantity = 0;
            foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) {
                if ( $values['quantity'] > 0 && $values['data']->needs_shipping() ) {
                    $total_quantity += $values['quantity'];
                }
            }
            return $total_quantity;
        }

        /**
         * Finds and returns shipping classes and the products with said class.
         * @param mixed $package
         * @return array
         */
        public function find_shipping_classes( $package ) {
            $found_shipping_classes = array();

            foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) {
                if ( $values['data']->needs_shipping() ) {
                    $found_class = $values['data']->get_shipping_class();

                    if ( ! isset( $found_shipping_classes[ $found_class ] ) ) {
                        $found_shipping_classes[ $found_class ] = array();
                    }

                    $found_shipping_classes[ $found_class ][ $item_id ] = $values;
                }
            }

            return $found_shipping_classes;
        }
    }
}

    function add_uk_shipping_method( $methods ) {
        $methods['uk_flat_rate'] = 'UK_WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_uk_shipping_method' );
}
}
```

Is there a setting in the plugin I'm missing to enforce the method is only zones based?
[image]

Comment: There are missing files to be able to test the code… So may be you can give the tutorial link or add missing files links **in your question itself**… Remember that: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add filters to remove the section and the first instance of the method from shipping like so

```
woocommerce_shipping_option_remove( $section ) {
    unset($section['uk_flat_rate']);
    return $section;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_shipping', 'woocommerce_shipping_option_remove' ,1 );
function woocommerce_shipping_remove_method( $rates ) 
{
    unset($rates['uk_flat_rate:1']);
    return $rates;
}
```

add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','woocommerce_shipping_remove_method', 100 );
         }
    }